# Puzzling use of 直立

Tags: translation

In the following passage from 永井荷風, 浮世絵の鑑賞, how is one to interpret 直立濶歩したりし? It appears to mean 'strode (around) erect', but 'erect' doesn't seem quite appropriate here. I wouldn't have thought that Japanese had problems 'walking erect' even in a traditional dwelling.

余は既に幾度か木にて造り紙にて張りたる日本伝来の家屋に住{じゅう}し春風秋雨四季の気候に対する郷土的感覚の如何を叙述したり。かくの如く脆弱にして清楚なる家屋とかくの如く湿気に満ち変化に富める気候の中{うち}に棲息すれば、かつて広大堅固なる西洋の居室に直立濶歩したりし時とは、百般の事自{おのずから}嗜好を異にするはけだし当然の事たるべし。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, the word 直立 is used not just to mean standing, but to convey the idea of standing with one's back straight and in a dignified manner, holding the head up high, like this AI-generated picture of a 直立不動の男:

[image: AI-generated picture of a 直立不動の男]

闊歩 also expresses how the author was able to walk comfortably without worrying about his surroundings. The combined expression 直立闊歩 signifies the sense of security and confidence the author could feel in a Western house.